# Xamarin cant load script in Razor cshtml

Tags: xamarin, razor, webview

I cant load script and css in cshtml page .

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="phonon.css" />
<script src="phonon.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have the js and css in Assets folder, as Android Assets.

I use a hybrid view and razor portable

```
var datapath = String.Format("/data/data/{0}/files/", Application.Context.PackageName);
var url = "file://" + datapath;
webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL(url, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Any ideas whats going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The base URL is used both to resolve relative URLs and when applying JavaScript's same origin policy.

So in your case to read `Assets`-based web content, the `baseURL` needs to be `file:///android_asset/`

```
webView.LoadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Comment: I have tried this that but i was missing the third slash (file:///) , thanks

Comment: @DevelopeCruz No problem, file-based urls always three (`file:///`) 